# Chef creating /service every time chef-client is ran

Tags: chef-infra

I have a recipe that will create /service and mount it when chef-client is ran. However, chef will mount /service even though it's already created and add it to fstab. I thought chef would know not to do this.

```
#mkdir /service
directory node['storm-prep']['service']['dir'] do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 00755
  action :create
 recursive true
end

#Create /service
lvm_logical_volume node['storm-prep']['service']['name'] do
    group node['storm-prep']['volume-group']['name']
    size node['storm-prep']['service']['size']
    filesystem node['storm-prep']['filesystem']['type']
    mount_point #{node['storm-prep']['service']['dir']}
    action [:create]
end

#mount /service and add to fstab
mount node['storm-prep']['service']['dir'] do
    device node['storm-prep']['service']['device']
    fstype node['storm-prep']['filesystem']['type']
end
```

End of chef-client error

```
014-08-19T16:19:31-05:00] FATAL: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: execute[mount /service and add to fstab] (storm-prep-cookbook::default line 41) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '32'
---- Begin output of echo '/dev/mapper/vg00-servicelv00  /service       ext4 defaults        0   0' >> /etc/fstab && mount /service ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: mount: /dev/mapper/vg00-servicelv00 already mounted or /service busy
mount: according to mtab, /dev/mapper/vg00-servicelv00 is already mounted on /service
---- End output of echo '/dev/mapper/vg00-servicelv00  /service       ext4 defaults        0   0' >> /etc/fstab && mount /service ----
Ran echo '/dev/mapper/vg00-servicelv00  /service       ext4 defaults        0   0' >> /etc/fstab && mount /service returned 32
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a so called [`guard`](http://docs.getchef.com/resource_common.html#guards): `not_if`. Like this:

```rb
mount node['storm-prep']['service']['dir'] do
    device node['storm-prep']['service']['device']
    fstype node['storm-prep']['filesystem']['type']
    # Don't execute the action if "/service" exists
    not_if "grep '/service' /etc/fstab"
end
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which step should not happen if `/service` exists?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. It seems to add /service to fstab every time chef client is ran, which shouldn't happen. Chef should know that service is already mounted and it shouldn't add it again.

Comment: You mean, if you are opening fstab in an editor, you realize that chef added the `/service` entry multiple times?

Comment: Yes, and Chef also errors out (Chef client wont finish). This may help? (added to post)

Comment: But yes, after chef-client crashes, I go to fstab, and it's in there multiple times

Comment: Ok, can you remove those entries and try the code I've posted?

Comment: Actually... This looks like a chef 10 issue... I'll comment back after I look into this.

Answer (score 0):

The fix is

```
#Create /service

mount_point #{node['storm-prep']['service']['dir']}
```

needs to be

```
#Create /service

mount_point node['storm-prep']['service']['dir']
```

And the whole #mount section can be removed

The root cause is the LVM cookbook having tons of issues and bad code